# Is it possible to migrate my iPhone 5c contacts to a Moto G with Android 5.1 installed by using Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, android, iphone

My iPhone 5c was almost destroyed. Luckily I have a backup in my PC, I use Ubuntu 16.04. I got a Moto G phone from a friend to replace my broken phone. It runs with Android 5.1. So now I want to "translate" this iPhone backup to info that can be understood by devices using Android, so that I can have access to my contacts, pictures, etc. Is it possible to do this? If so, how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How was the backup made?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this, one of which will be fast and easy, the other of which uses Ubuntu.

**Fast and Easy**

1. Get a google g-mail account.
2. Sync your iphone contacts to google
3. Edit your contacts on the google webpage (if desired)
4. Hook your android phone up to sync with your google acount
5. Sync your contacts...

**Using your Ubuntu installation**

If you have time and energy, you can setup a CardDav server on your ubuntu system.

Install [Radicale](https://radicale.org/documentation/) a CardDav server.  This is available in the [Ubuntu Universe Repository[(https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=radicale), and can be installed via

```
sudo apt install radicale
```

If you do not have `pip` installed

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Now Finish the installation

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade radicale
```

And run Radicale with a basic configuration.

```
python3 -m radicale --config "" --storage-filesystem-folder=~/.var/lib/radicale/collections
```

Login to Radicale on a web browser at address http://localhost:5232/ and create a user or two.

There is a bit of setup that can be done to make a secure Radical, and more setup if you want to run it as a service at startup.  This will require reading through the setup guide at https://radicale.org/setup/

Your android phone will need to be able to connect to your server, which required a download from the Play Store.  [This link](https://www.carddavserver.com/connecting/android/) is for one such application, and hopefully you are in the same local network, or can ping your newly installed server.  If so you should be able to connect your android to the server.  Being lazy, I will not check this.

Your iphone will also need to connect to the CardDav server.  This [link from iMore](https://www.imore.com/how-set-mail-contacts-and-calendars-iphone-and-ipad#other) describes a method to connect your iphone to the server.  Not having an I phone, I will not verify this!

Assuming that you have setup both phones correctly, they should be synchronizing and sharing Contact info at this time.

---

**Bonus Section**

You can also synchronize Thunderbird with this contact info!  [Provider for CalDAV & CardDAV](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-GB/thunderbird/addon/dav-4-tbsync/?src=search) provides an extension to sync your Thunderbird account!